# Performance optimizing use of generated XmlSerializer class

Tags: c#, .net, performance, xml-serialization

We have a few XML files that are being read by our applications. The XML format is fixed, and thus we can read them very easily with [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx).

I use this code to read the XML files and convert them to classes:

```
public static T FromXml<T>(this string xml) where T : class
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(xml))
    {
        return default(T);
    }

    XmlSerializer xmlserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

    XmlTextReader textReader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(xml));
    textReader.Normalization = false;

    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();

    T value;

    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(textReader, settings))
    {
        value = (T)xmlserializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }

    return value;
}
```

However, there are some performance issues. When calling this code for the first time a specific type for `T` is used, the `XmlSerializer` generates a `Project.XmlSerializer.dll` file.

This is fine, but costs some precious milliseconds (about 900ms in my case). This can be circumvented by generating that assembly on forehand, using the [XML Serializer Generator (sgen)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk3w6240(v=vs.110).aspx). This brings down the time to about half. Primarily due to the reading and reflection of the assembly.

I want to **optimize this further, by bringing the `XmlSerializer` classes inside the assembly the actual classes are in**, but I can't find a way to let `XmlSerializer` know not to read an external assembly, but use the serializer from the current assembly.

Any thoughts how to do this or an alternative way to make this work? (I can't pre-load them since most of the serialized classes are used at start-up)

---

The analysis using ANTS Profiler (metrics from other machine, but same pattern):

[image]

Plain. Most of the time (300ms + 400ms = 700ms) is lost in generating and loading the XmlSerializer assembly.

[image]

With sgen generated assembly. Most of the time (336ms) is lost in loading the XmlSerializer assembly.

[image]

When including the actual source of the assembly inside the project, and calling the serializer directly, the action goes down to 456ms (was 1s in first, 556ms in second).

Comment: Not related to the question: You don't need `reader.Close();` as using statement does that for you via `Dispose`.

Comment: I can't understand what you mean in last paragraph starting *I want to optimize this further, by bringing the XmlSerializer classes...* Can you make it bit clear? I'll give my try then :)

Comment: If loading the dll is the only problem you feel. You can just open the file and close it immediately(in another thread as soon as the app starts) (If you know the path). OS will cache the file in cache, so that next attempt to read the file(by clr) will be fast. Forget if I said something dumb without understanding you :(

Comment: IS a single execution the normal way your app will operate? If generating/loading assemblies takes a long time and your app is using the FromXml many times you should do a more realistic performance test where you'd deserialize various data to see the *actual* deserialization performance.

Comment: UserSettings are read on start-up and saved when closing. There are some other xml files that usually have the same pattern. (Btw, the second time it is fast indeed, but I want to minimize start-up time)

Comment: Just for giggles: can you attach an event listener to AppDomain's `FirstChanceException` event and count the times it's called while deserializing? I had an issue like that a while back

Comment: @StenPetrov: Just tried. Not getting called.

Comment: can you share a sample xml that's reasonably real?

Comment: @StenPetrov: Check http://pastebin.com/d67nch3R.

Comment: Try removing the namespace declarations

Comment: @StenPetrov: Won't help. It's auto-generated and it isn't the root cause of the problem (analyzed that already).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are doing the serialization at the very app startup, one way would be to force CLR to load and even compile whatever classes you're using ahead of time, possibly in a thread which would run in background as soon as you've started your app.

Something like, for example:

```
foreach (Assembly a in assembliesThatShouldBeCompileed)
    foreach (Type type in a.GetTypes())
        if (!type.IsAbstract && type.IsClass)
        {
            foreach (MethodInfo method in type.GetMethods(
                                BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly |
                                BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                BindingFlags.Public |
                                BindingFlags.Instance |
                                BindingFlags.Static))
            {
                if (method.ContainsGenericParameters || 
                    method.IsGenericMethod || 
                    method.IsGenericMethodDefinition)
                    continue;

                if ((method.Attributes & MethodAttributes.PinvokeImpl) > 0)
                    continue;

                System.Runtime.CompilerServices
                   .RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod(method.MethodHandle);
            }
        }
```

It's strange, however, that your profiling seems to indicate that there is not much difference if the SGEN'd code is in a separate assembly, while loading seems to be the bottleneck. I wonder how the graph looks like for the case where they are in the same assembly?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This would indeed work if I wouldn't need them at start-up, but I do... :(

Comment: @Patrick: one detail, how does the profiler chart look for the "1.7s" case?

Comment: I updated the question. The strange this is that most of the time then is in reading the config file, not creating the serializer itself.

Comment: Actually, `XmlSerializer1.CreateReader()` shouldn't actually load the the file at all (it only creates an instance of `XmlSerializationReader1` in the serialization assembly), so the overhead in that case is due to something else. What happens in these two branches below that call?

Comment: It reads the app.config file. Still digging in the reference source to see why.

Comment: Found the actual place: it tries to read the [`<system.xml.serialization>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229756(v=vs.110).aspx) section.

Comment: Redid the profiling. Added longer trace on last one.

Comment: @Patrick: so, the bottleneck boils down to `ConfigurationManager.GetSection`, which initializes the config system and then reads app.config. I am not sure if that can be efficiently hacked. By looking at ILSpy it seems to be accessing registry and doing various config stuff depending on your machine (I am not sure which exact conditions happen in your case). On the other hand, is it possible to simply switch to a different settings file format (e.g. protobuf)?

Comment: Yes. I didn't notice before, but the two slower options read config too, but using a different route (not sure why). That is 270ms to gain. Using different serializers is possible, but for this problem I had like to focus on XML (also for future reference).

Comment: Is your `app.config` large? Does it potentially use some sections which would cause cfg manager to have to load other assemblies? I.e. the `<configSections>` part?

Comment: Groo, I totally messed up. Please see my last comment under the other answer. You have been very helpful, just like the other guy. I don't see the need to spend more time on this (from both sides). Then there is left, the bounty. Since you have quite some rep, I want to suggest to accept your answer, but award the bounty to the other guy. Is that fair to you?

Comment: @Patrick: sure, seems fair, I am glad to hear that the thing works after all.

Comment: Thanks. Will do so. Have to wait a few hours. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Note: OP posted a sample config: http://pastebin.com/d67nch3R

Based on the sample config and the type of issue you're experiencing there are a couple brute-force ways, pretty much guaranteed to do the trick, both boiling down to abandoning the XML serializer altogether

**Route #1**

Abandon XML serialization and use [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387050.aspx) to get data out of the XML.

**Route #2**

Use json and  [Newtonsoft Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/) to store and load configs. It should perform a lot better than XML Serializer

The sample json counterpart would look like this:

```
{
  "Connections": {
    "-default": "Local\\SqlServer",
    "-forcedefault": "false",
    "group": {
      "-name": "Local",
      "connection": {
        "-name": "SqlServer",
        "database": {
          "-provider": "SqlServer",
          "-connectionString": "blah"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "LastLanguage": "en",
  "UserName": "un",
  "SavePassword": "true",
  "AutoConnect": "false",
  "Password": "someObfuscatedHashedPassword==",
  "ConnectionName": "Somewhere\\Database",
  "LastAvailableBandwidth": "0",
  "LastAvailableLatency": "0",
  "DateLastConnectionSuccesful": "2014-08-13T15:21:35.9663654+02:00"
}
```

And load it:

```
UserSettings settings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserSettings>(File.ReadAllText("settings.json"))
```

Comment: your issue is startup time, the answer *is* specific by nature

Comment: I tried your JSON approach. After running a few profiling sessions it seems JSON is just a little slower than the XmlSerializer approach (JSON = 650ms vs XML  556ms (second timing used since that fitted the JSON more)).

Comment: something odd is going on because in LinqPad I get the json to load in 0.035s

Comment: Are you trying to connect to the database as soon as some of the properties on your UserSettings class is changed?

Comment: No, I had a stripped console application which only reads and writes the file.

Comment: Can you share the source?

Comment: can you run the app on another machine with just `Console.WriteLine(Stopwatch.Elapsed)` in the end, no profiler attached

Comment: With the JSON approach?

Comment: with either or with both, at least about the json I'm convinced the 650ms is an anomaly

Comment: You are right. I totally missed something. I was too focussed on the results in ANTS. The program, when ran alone took 14ms (after my optimizations). That other 600 ms was overhead from ANTS (which should be filtered out, but didn't). Implementing JSON doesn't change this that much I want to trade in XML.

Comment: Thanks for your time, I will see what to do with the bounty. You will notice it shortly.

Comment: Agreed with Groo to accept his answer and reward you with the bounty since you pointed me in the right direction after all. Thanks again. Have to wait for a day until I can award it.